# Error in shell script if condition

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I didnt understand what he error here as iam new to shell scripting. Please help me

```
./bpr: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./bpr: line 8: `    if[$(grep -o BPR $file | wc -l) == 1]; then '
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add spaces between your `[` `]`, try this:

```
if [ $(grep -o BPR $file | wc -l) == 1 ]; then
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a space around your condition:

```
if [ $(grep -o BPR $file | wc -l) == 1 ]; then
    ^                                 ^
```

1) If you are using bash, you can use the built-in `[[ ..]]` instead of `test` (`[ ...]`) command.

2) You can also avoid `wc` by using `-c` option of grep.

```
if [[ $(grep -c -o BPR $file) == 1 ]]; then
```

Comment: You need to add a space after the if.

Comment: Yes. Just struggling with the edit options ;-) Still not sure how to format the last line similar to the first line of my answer :D

Comment: +1 for your nice use of grep :).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from your syntax errors, you don't need `wc` either if you don't care that there may be multiple occurrances of `BPR` in the file:

```
if grep -o BPR "$file"; then
```

Comment: You don't need wc either way: `grep -c -o BPR`

Comment: I was relying on the exit code to distinguish between "no matches" and "at least one match". With `-c`, you would still need to capture the value and make a comparison if there was a valid distinction between, say, 1 match and 2.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- You need spaces around `[` and `]`.
- You probably don't want to use `[` and `]`.

The `if` statement runs the command you give it. If the command returns a zero, the `then` portion of the `if` statement is executed. If the command returns a non-zero, the `else` portion (if it exists) is executed.

Try this:

```
$ if ls some.file.name.that.does.not.exist
> then
>     echo "Hey, the file exists!"
> else
>     echo "Nope. File isn't there"
> fi
```

You'll get an output:

```
ls: some.file.name.that.does.not.exist: No such file or directory
Nope. File isn't there
```

That first statement, of course is the output of your `ls` command. The second one is the output from the `if` statement. The `ls` ran, but couldn't access that file (it doesn't exist) and returned e `1`. That caused the `else` clause to execute.

Try this:

```
$ touch foo
$ if ls foo
>     echo "Hey, the file exists!"
> else
>     echo "Nope. File isn't there"
> fi
```

You'll get an output:

```
foo
Hey, the file exists!
```

Again the first line is your output from `ls`. Since the file exists, and is statable, `ls` returned a `0`. This caused the `if` clause to execute, printing the second line.

What if I want to *test* whether or not a file exists?

You can use the [test](http://man.cx/test) command:

```
$ if test -e foo
> then
>     echo "Hey, the file exists!"
> else
>     echo "Nope. File isn't there"
> fi
```

If the file `foo` exists, the test command returns a 0. That means the `echo "Hey, the file exists!"` will execute. If the file doesn't exist, test will return a 1, and the `else` clause will execute.

Now do this:

```
$ ls -il /bin/test /bin/[
10958 -rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  18576 May 28 22:27 /bin/[
10958 -rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  18576 May 28 22:27 /bin/test
```

That first number is the `inode`. If two matching files have the same inode, they are hard linked to each other. The `[`... `]` are merely another name for the `test` command. The `[` is an actual command. That's why you need spaces around it. You also see that `if` tests whether or not a command succeeds, and doesn't really do boolean checking (the exception is if you use double square brackets like `[[` and `]]`  instead of `[` and `]`. These are built into the shell and not as builtin commands.)

What you probably want to do is:

```
if grep -q "BPR" "$file"
then
    echo "'BPR' is in '$file'"
fi
```

The `-q` flag tells `grep` to shut its yap. The `grep` command will return a `0` if the pattern you give it is in the file, and a non-zero (exact value doesn't matter -- as long as it isn't 0) if it can't.

Note I don't need `[` ... `]` because I am using the output of the grep command to see if I should execute the if clause of that statement.

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to know if the string matches without showing the actual match use

```
if grep -q 'anystring' file ; then
```